# EWS API Deleting appoinments from Outlook calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

**Hello,
Do any of you people know if there has been changes to the EWS C# API? I have an automated batch application that usually runs fine, but for the last 1-2 weeks, it cannot delete marked calendars and update them. If not, can anybody maybe point me in direction of where I can find the Patch releases / notes to see if anything changed?**

```
 class Program {
    private const int ParallelCount = 3;
    private static string[] ErrorRepportRecipients = new string[] { "xx", "xx" };
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void FlashWindow(IntPtr a, bool b);
    private static ExtendedPropertyDefinition SafeAppointmentFlag = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "SAFE_APPOINTMENT_FLAG", MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Title = "SAFE til Exchange synkronisering";
        Console.BufferHeight = 1000;
        Console.BufferWidth = 120;
        Console.SetWindowSize(120, 30);
        Console.WriteLine("Starter Exchange kalender synkronisering");
        if(SystemVars.IsProductionEnvironment()) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Program.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
           // ApplicationLog.LogEvent(ApplicationLogEntry.CreateLogEntryForAgent("Application started", LogTypes.Notification));
            NDBusiness.Audit.Environment.CheckApplicationState();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Forbinder til Exchange... (" + ParallelCount + " forbindelser)");
        ConcurrentQueue<ExchangeService> serviceQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<ExchangeService>();
        Parallel.For(0, ParallelCount, i => {
            serviceQueue.Enqueue(EWS.GetService("xx@xx.dk", new WebCredentials("xx@xx.dk", "xx")));
            Console.WriteLine("Forbindelse " + (i + 1).ToString() + " klar");
        });
        var syncronizer = new SafeScheduleSyncronizer();
        #region Delete
        if(args.Contains("delete")) {
            int attemptedDeleteCount = 0;
            int deletedCount = 0;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Kører rydning af markerede kalendere");
          //  if(SystemVars.IsProductionEnvironment())
           //     ApplicationLog.LogEvent(ApplicationLogEntry.CreateLogEntryForAgent("Calendar delete started", LogTypes.BatchRun));
            ConcurrentBag<Exception> exceptions = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();
            List<string> permissionEx = new List<string>();
            List<string> noGuidEx = new List<string>();
            using(var conn = new SCDriftConnection()) {
                var agentsMarkedForCalendarClear = SAFEAgent.GetAgents(conn, new QueryParameters<SAFEAgent, SAFEAgent.ExchangeSettings>((a, e) => e.DeleteAll == true));
                try {
                    Parallel.ForEach(agentsMarkedForCalendarClear,
                                     new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ParallelCount },
                                     a => {
                                         ExchangeService service;
                                         var dequeued = serviceQueue.TryDequeue(out service);
                                         if(dequeued)
                                             try {
                                                 Interlocked.Increment(ref attemptedDeleteCount);
                                                 using(var scDriftConn = new SCDriftConnection()) {
                                                     try {
                                                         Console.WriteLine("Rydder kalender for " + a.Initials);
                                                         //  syncronizer.DeleteAllSafeApointments(scDriftConn, service, a, new ClosedRange<DateTime>(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7), DateTime.Today.AddDays(14)));
                                                         syncronizer.DeleteAllSafeApointments(scDriftConn, service, a);
                                                         Console.WriteLine("Kalender ryddet for " + a.Initials);
                                                         Interlocked.Increment(ref deletedCount);
                                                     } catch(Exception ex) {
                                                         if(ex.InnerException != null) {
                                                             if(ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException) {
                                                                 if(ex.InnerException.Message == "Agent has not assigned editor permissions") {
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.HasCalendarEditorPermission = false;
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(conn);
                                                                     Console.WriteLine("Rettigheder til kalender mangler for " + a.Initials);
                                                                     permissionEx.Add(a.Initials);
                                                                 } else
                                                                     exceptions.Add(ex.InnerException);
                                                             } else if(ex.InnerException is ServiceResponseException) {
                                                                 if (ex.InnerException.Message.ValueIn("The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.", "The specified folder could not be found in the store."))
                                                                 {
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.HasCalendarEditorPermission = false;
                                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(conn);
                                                                     Console.WriteLine("Rettigheder til kalender mangler for " + a.Initials);
                                                                     permissionEx.Add(a.Initials);
                                                                 }
                                                                 else
                                                                 {
                                                                     exceptions.Add(ex.InnerException);
                                                                     if (ex.InnerException.Message.ToUpper().StartsWith("NO MAILBOX WITH SUCH GUID"))
                                                                     {
                                                                         noGuidEx.Add(a.Initials);
                                                                     }
                                                                 }

                                                             } else if(ex.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
                                                                 throw;
                                                         } else
                                                             exceptions.Add(new Exception("Error during calendar delete of " + a.Initials + ".", ex));
                                                     }
                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.DeleteAll = false;
                                                     a.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(scDriftConn);
                                                 }
                                             } finally {
                                                 serviceQueue.Enqueue(service);
                                             }
                                         else
                                             throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not dequeue service.");
                                     });
                } catch(AggregateException ex) {
                    throw ex.InnerExceptions.First();
                }
            }
            if(exceptions.Count > 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Der opstod fejl ved " + exceptions.Count + " opdateringer");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Rydning af markerede kalendere færdig (" + deletedCount + "/" + attemptedDeleteCount + " ryddet)");
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: What line of code throws an exception? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: agree with @EugeneAstafiev. if you could point out where it fails and with the exception?

Comment: No exceptions happening, but still not updating the Outlook Calendar or the database row

Comment: It runs through the Write lines like it did its job but its not really doing anything

Comment: we used to do something like this https://gist.github.com/Bhaal22/05025419e9f203e04d89cd8d12135307